# What does ‘towards the end of the week’ exactly mean?

Tags: american-english

If someone says to me that I can call her towards the end of the week, what does it exactly mean?

Should I...

call her anytime from now until the end of the week?

not call her until nearly the end of the week?

call her anytime but preferably at the end of the week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the third option:

> call her anytime but preferably at the end of the week

As we see, towards means:

> in the direction of.

So the meaning should be:

> call her anytime in the direction of end of the week